# sem aspas o suficiente para passar uma string javascript html

Tags: javascript, onclick

estou enfrentando uma dificuldade, tenho que criar tags, que vão ter uma função ao clicar, o problema é que, eu tenho que passar uma string no elemento no html ou seja, ao chamar a função e passar como parâmetro, preciso utilizar aspas, mas acabou as opções no javascript.

```
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr id="'+obj[i].id+file+'"><td>'+obj[i].id+'</td><td>'+obj[i].name+'</td><td align="center" valign="top"><img src="'+obj[i].picture+'"/></td><td><button onclick="remove('+obj[i].id+file+')">Excluir</button><br/><button onclick="Alterar('+obj[i].id+')">Alterar</button></td></tr>';
```

o elemento em especifico está no `<td onclick="remove('+***+')">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta somente escapar o caracter, isso é feito utilizando a barra invertida "\". Sendo assim ficaria da seguinte forma

```
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr id="'+obj[i].id+file+'"><td>'+obj[i].id+'</td><td>'+obj[i].name+'</td><td align="center" valign="top"><img src="'+obj[i].picture+'"/></td><td><button onclick="remove(\''+obj[i].id+file+'\')">Excluir</button><br/><button onclick="Alterar('+obj[i].id+')">Alterar</button></td></tr>';
```

Ou como no seu exemplo

```
<td onclick="remove(\''+***+'\')">
```

Por exemplo, adicionando algo na table

```
document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = '<td onclick="remove(\''+***+'\')">';
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Resolveu direitinho. Thanks!